# Sign in to install important updates

Tags: windows, windows-8, updates

Windows 8 started showing up this message 'Sign in to install important updates' in the bottom right side of the login screen each time after booting up. But each time when I login no updates are installed, so I get this message now everytime I turn on the computer for a week now.

How do I get rid of this message/install the updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried going into Control Panel -> System -> Automatic Updates and manually telling it to check for updates?  Also, try "wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow" from a command-line, wait a while, and see if it tells you there are any more updates.  And see what c:\windows\windowsupdate.log has to say at the bottom; it should have a "no updates found" message towards the bottom.

Comment: Hi. I checked the log and found out Windows Firewall was blocking the Windows updates service or something. I set svchost.exe to allow all incoming and outgoing, but is it safe doing that? Adding separate IPs is crazy, because running that cmd line svchost tries to contact like 100 different IPs and misc ports.

Comment: Well, as svchost runs many different services, you may be opening more to the Internet than you want.  However, if I read other articles correctly, you should be able to restrict it to TCP ports 80 and 443, and it should continue to work.